# Which procedure in Moqui transforms XML Screen into script?

Tags: moqui

I would like to see what is happening behind the scenes when the engine transforms XML file with screen definition into Groovy (I suppose) script. So that I can see the definition turning into more readable script, hopefully.

Where shall I place the breakpoint while debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, in Tools (/apps/tools/Service) if you click on 'Service detail' you get a nicely rendered view of the generated groovy for any of your services called from screens (or otherwise called). 'Services' are a very intuitive unit for debugging in moqui.

Comment: This was a good one. The tool is really useful. I am not quite sure I understand what exactly being 'very intuitive unit for debugging' means. But, neveretheless, you really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

XML Screens are not transformed into scripts like XML Actions are. XML Screens and Forms are transformed by FreeMarker macros into the desired output text (html, xsl-fo, csv, etc). These macros are defined in the DefaultScreenMacros.html.ftl file for html output, and similarly named files (in the runtime/template/screen-macro directory) for other types of output.

Comment: OK, I understand your answer in a way, that it is not a good idea to get deeper through debugger. A small progress, but still at least there is some.